# Sitecore webform for marketer posting submit action to layout instead of an item

Tags: sitecore

We have setup a webform using webform for marketer module in sitecore.

Using this module, we are creating web forms where users can fill details and submit the form. On submit, we can do actions such as storing in database, send email etc.

Now we were able to creat such form using webform for marketer module in sitecore. Now the problem is when user fill the form and hit submit button, instead of posting this action to the page, request is getting redirected to layout in sitecore. This is a same layout we are using to resolve the page on backend.

Comment: what exactly are you trying to do?  what action are you using for the submit button?

Comment: I am posting back to the page.

Comment: Not only your question is rather vague, but also your explaination is. Rewrite your question more detailed so we can help you please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found solution on this link.

http://sdn.sitecore.net/SDN5/Forum/ShowPost.aspx?postid=37264

For some reason App_Browser folder was missing from site. Once i put that folder in. It started working.

Also, i was reading on sitecore sdn site that, in 6.4.1 version, they are removing need for App_Browser